# nodejs twitter api get oauth access token and secret from request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working on a script to get user's home timeline from twitter.

Currently I'm using access token and secret from my developer account itself and I am only able to get home timeline of this user only.

I want the frontend to make other users authorize this app and retrieve respective tokens and secrets and pass these to server when hitting the endpoint.

```
const {
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
} = process.env as any;

class TwitterFeed {
  public path = "/tweet";
  public router = express.Router();
  // this instance is used for app-auth context only
  private T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token: TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret: TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  });

....
....
private homeTimeline = async (request:Request, reponse:Response, next: NextFunction) => {
 try {
  // create new Twit instance for this one..
  // with request ACCESS_TOKEN and SECRET
  const tw = new Twit({
    consumer_key: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    // access token from post body
    access_token: request.body.access_token, 
    // access token secret from post body
    access_token_secret: request.body.access_token_secret,
  });
  const tweets: any = await tw.get('statuses/home_timeline', { count: 20 });
  const data = tweets.data.map((tweet: any) => {
    return {
      created_at: tweet.created_at,
      id_str: tweet.id_str,
      text: tweet.text,
      entities: tweet.entities,
      retweet_count: tweet.retweet_count,
      favorite_count: tweet.favorite_count
    };
  });
  reponse.send(data);
} catch (error) {
  next(error);
}    
  }
```

Here my assumption being frontend handles the user authentication against our app and sends `access_token` and `access_token_secret` values when hitting endpoint for `home Timeline`.

Is this a proper way of doing it?

Comment: What you're doing is fine, you just need to implement the Sign in with Twitter flow and store the user access token and access token secret, and I don't see that in your code here.

Comment: @AndyPiper this part will be handled in the frontend part.

Comment: OK, I guess I'm still not sure what your question is?